# Does stationarity of Poisson processes mean $\Bbb P(N(s,t]) = \Bbb P(N(s+h,t+h])$?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I am supposed to find the probability for some given $s,t,h > 0$, the probability 
$$N(s,t] = N (s+h,t+h] +m$$ 
for $m\in\Bbb N$.

I am confused by this however because I thought stationarity meant $N(s,t] = N (s+h,t+h] = k$.

Doesn't having a constant $m$ violate this?

Comment: $N(s,t] \overset{d}{=} N (s+h,t+h] $ in distribution. That doesn't mean the actual realizations are equal. For example, if I tell you that $N(0,1) = 5$, does that mean you know what the value of $N(0+.5,1+.5) = N(.5,1.5)$ is? No.

Comment: @probablyme Ah, of course or it would not be random. Hmm, one thing that confuses me is that, so far, I am only able to find the probabilities of events in the form $\Bbb P(N(0,1] = 5)$. For several of the problems, I was given statements like $N(0,3] = N(0,4]$ and could reduce it to $N(3,4) = 0$ because the intervals overlapped. However, suppose $s+h > t$, then they won't overlap so I am uncertain how to think about relating the events like that.

Comment: I was also told using a Bessel function here would be appropriate. Does that sound sensible to you?

Comment: For every nonnegative $u$, consider $p(u)=P(X_u=Y_u+m)$ where $X_u$ and $Y_u$ are i.i.d. Poisson with parameter $\lambda u$. If $t\le s+h$, $(s,t]\cap(s+h,t+h]=\varnothing$ hence the desired probability is $p(t-s)$. If $t> s+h$, the event of interest is the event that $N(s,s+h]=N(t,t+h]$ hence the desired probability is $p(h)$. To sum up, the desired probability is $p(\min(t-s,h))$. Finally, for every $u$, $$p(u)=e^{-2u}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{u^{2k+m}}{k!(k+m)!}=I_m(2u),$$ where $I_m$ is a modified Bessel function.

Comment: @Did I dont quite follow why if $t\le s+h$, $(s,t]\cap(s+h,t+h]=\varnothing$ hence the desired probability is $p(t-s)$. Why is the probability the length of the smaller interval instead of the larger one? We know the two intervals dont intersect but why does that mean $u=t-s$?

Comment: Are you in trouble to understand why, if $t\le s+h$ then $(s,t]\cap(s+h,t+h]=\varnothing$, or why, if $(s,t]\cap(s+h,t+h]=\varnothing$ then $P(N(s,t]=N(s+h,t+h]+m)=P(X_{t-s}=Y_{t-s}+m)$, where $X_{t-s}$ and $Y_{t-s}$ are i.i.d. Poisson with parameter $t-s$? "Why is the probability the length of the smaller interval instead of the larger one?" 'Cause I showed it is. "We know the two intervals dont intersect" Huhh?

Comment: @Did yes, that is the part I am having trouble understanding exactly.

Comment: Again: first part or second part?

Comment: @Did Everything up to $t-s$ I don't understand. Specifically, I don't get what $X_{u}$ denotes. I am only used to calculating probabilities such as $\Bbb P (N(0,1)) = 2$. I can also find it for two Poisson processes defined at points, like $N(4) - N(3) = 5$. But I do not know what to do for a situation like $\Bbb P (N(0,1) = N(0,1) + m$

Comment: @Did I asked someone to help me understand it and I now understand your remarks. Thanks very much. That answered everything.

Comment: Cool-even though we will never know what was causing you trouble...